# Spotfire Refresh data option is disabled

Tags: spotfire

I have a Spotfire table which gets refreshed with new data from access table every week. This was working fine until today. The 'Refresh data' option is suddenly disabled. I am not sure why.

I tried reloading data which didn't work. New data is not being picked.

I also tried replacing the data table but calculated columns are being left out.

Please advise. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like whenever a new column is added to a Spotfire table (main table) from another Spotfire table, refresh data option is disabled for the main table.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the source data table no longer exists. Look at the Source Information tab for more info. Adding a new column shouldn't break it. The join will be reapplied on refresh.